# Nullpoint Exception in retrieving Google direction in android

Tags: java, android

I followed a example through this link about retriving direction between two locations, https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android

But I'm getting an error like below. This is my log:

```
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.nirma.abcde, PID: 21943
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nirma.abcde/com.example.nirma.abcde.ShortestPath.RoadMap}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.example.nirma.abcde.ShortestPath.RoadMap
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.example.nirma.abcde.ShortestPath.RoadMap
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:279)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.nirma.abcde.ShortestPath.RoadMap.onCreate(RoadMap.java:82)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder$1.findView(ButterKnife.java:91)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findOptionalView(ButterKnife.java:152)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.nirma.abcde.ShortestPath.RoadMap$$ViewBinder.bind(RoadMap$$ViewBinder.java:11)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.nirma.abcde.ShortestPath.RoadMap$$ViewBinder.bind(RoadMap$$ViewBinder.java:8)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:279) 
11-20 17:06:08.909 21943-21943/com.example.nirma.abcde E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.nirma.abcde.ShortestPath.RoadMap.onCreate(RoadMap.java:82)
```

Where does it go wrong? Please help me with this.
How i can get the places between these two locations?? Please help me with this.

Comment: Please provide us a MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Provide us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The guess is that within your code you have a line with

```
someObject.findViewByInt(someInt)
```

where the `View` object is null.

Comment: I able to get the result. Error was in the view. Thank you.